# Не добавилась репутция за новый день

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

Вчера у меня было 2958 репутации, сегодня утром увидел уведомление о +30 репутации, но у меня показывает 2968. Я знаю что есть ограничение на кол-во репутации в течении 1-ого дня - это 200 репутации. Хорошо, что при открытии с компа страница не обновилась сама и я могу вам показать это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но сейчас же вроде следующий день наступил, почему не все голоса защитались?

Всё что пришло в голову - это то что счётчик репутации не сбрасывается каждый день условно в `00:00`, а я не могу получить больше 200 репутации в течении 24-х часов. Это правда или в моём случае какие-то другие обстоятельства на это повлияли?

Comment: [Согласованность в конечном счёте](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Согласованность_в_конечном_счёте), [Eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). В современных системах некритичные данные обновляются постепенно. Рано или поздно система придёт в согласованное состояние.